# can "typeof Zip" invoke its member directly

Tags: typescript

I read the TypeScript [handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios) now, in Optional Module Loading section, I met the example like below:

```
declare var require;
import Zip = require('./ZipCodeValidator');

if (needZipValidation) {
    require(['./ZipCodeValidator'], (x: typeof Zip) => {
        if (x.isAcceptable('...')) { /* ... */ }
    });
}
```

my question is since

> x:typeof Zip

is it correct usage in the example that like

> x.isAcceptable('...')

I think since x represents the "class ZipCodeValidator", you cannot call the class member directly without get an instance of the class first.

I also tested this code in an Visual Studio, the IDE shows that statement x.isAccetable('...') is not valid.

*For a reference, I extracted the code for ZipCodeValidator from the handbook as below:*

```
import validation = require('./Validation');
    var numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    class ZipCodeValidator implements validation.StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
    export = ZipCodeValidator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, a type of `typeof Zip` refers to the Zip (ZipCodeValidator) constructor, whereas a type of `Zip` refers to an instance of the Zip type.

So, the `typeof Zip` type in the `require` call is correct, since that is the correct type for the imported object `x` (though one would not need to do this as it is already imported by `import` statement)—but the attempt to use `x.isAcceptable` is wrong, since `isAcceptable` is a member of an *instance* of Zip, not a member of the constructor function (in other words, it is not a static class member).

For `isAcceptable` to be usable as a member of the constructor, one would need to declare it using the `static` keyword (`static isAcceptable(s: string) …`).

Otherwise, you’d need to do one of these things:

1. Instantiate the type using the constructor function first in order to access the member function (`new x().isAcceptable(…)`).
2. Access `isAcceptable` via the prototype of the class constructor (`x.prototype.isAcceptable`).

Comment: Thank you, this is close to what I am thinking, so the example in the TS official site has something wrong. The link (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios) is what I firstly pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

what does your Zip class look like?

In general if you have an object of type Zip then you can call it's members.

For example this would work just fine

```
import Zip = require('./ZipCodeValidator');

Zip.isAcceptable('...');
```

this does assume isAcceptable is a static function in your zip class. Otherwise you do need to have an instance of your object

```
import Zip = require('./ZipCodeValidator');

x = new Zip();
x.isAcceptable('...');
```

Your class does need to be loaded 'somehow' and your import ... require tells me you have some kind of module loading turned on.

You could do with without module loading but then you needed to reference the other files

```
/// <reference path="./ZipCodeValidator"/>
```

if you do that you can call the code in the other class 'directly'. In general i wouldn't recommend going without module loading though.